# How to change bar graph style

Tags: matlab, graph, graphics, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a bar graph, and set every bar a different style (lines, dots, circles and ext...).

In this example:

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
bar(x,y);
```

All 3 bars have the same style.

How can I change it and set 3 differents styles for the 3 bars ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding some style changes to what @Luis given

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
h = bar(x,y);
set(h(1),'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle',':');
set(h(2),'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle','--');
set(h(3),'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle','-.');
```

`'FaceColor', 'w'` -- Makes the color of bar white

`'LineWidth', 1` -- Width of the border line of bar

`'LineStyle',':'` -- Dotted line

`'LineStyle','--'` -- Dashed line

`'LineStyle','-.'` -- Dash-dot line

[image]

**For different style for each bar set**

```
figure
hold on;
y = [2 2 3; 0 0 0; 0 0 0;0 0 0 ];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
z=bar(x,y);
ylim([0 15]);
set(z,'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle',':');
y = [0 0 0; 2 5 6; 0 0 0;0 0 0 ];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
z1=bar(x,y);
set(z1,'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle','-.');
y = [0 0 0;0 0 0; 2 8 9; 0 0 0];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
z2=bar(x,y);
set(z2,'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle','-');
y = [0 0 0;0 0 0; 0 0 0; 2 11 12];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
z4=bar(x,y);
set(z4,'FaceColor', 'w','LineWidth', 1, 'LineStyle','--');
hold off;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a handle output when calling `bar`

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
x = [10; 20; 50; 90];
h = bar(x,y);
```

That gives an array `h` of `bar` objects (of length `3` in your example), and you can set their aspect independently. For example,

```
set(h(1), 'EdgeColor', 'r');
set(h(2), 'EdgeColor', 'g');
set(h(3), 'EdgeColor', 'b');
```

gives the following graph in R2015b (the aspect will vary in other versions). 
[image]

Other properties you can change are `'BarWidth'`, `'LineStyle'`, etc. To see the list type `get(h(1))`.